# character vector indexing Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have the following character vector:

```
test = [sprintf('(1,2)\n(1,3)\n(1,4)')]

test = 
(1,2)
(1,3)
(1,4)
```

How do I make the indexing so that when I type `test(1)` it returns (1,2). and `test(2) = (1,3)` And `test(2) = (1,4)`. Is it possible to split a character vector by new line character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `strsplit` which returns a cell array

```
c=strsplit(test,'\n')
```

As this is a cell indexing is done with `{}`, for example `c{1}`

Comment: On old Matlab versions (that don't have `strsplit`): `c = regexp(test,'\n','split')`

Comment: thanks @Daniel. I thought I was going to have to make a for loop to get test(1:5), test(6:11), test(12:17) into a new array. this is a lot easier!